# How to change recent App thumbnail?

Tags: user-interface, broadcastreceiver, android

On press of recent app button, it shows recently opened application in thumbnail with its previous state.

i.e - If you are on Activity "A" and close app then on press of recent app button, it shows your app thumbnail with screen shot of Activity "A". Activity "A" will see in App thumbnail.

But my requirement is slightly different.

I want to show black/blank screen instead of any activity.

So when you see the app thumbnail from recent app, it should always show the black/blank screen.

Is it possible?

Is it possible to get time when  android take screenshot of app to show in recent app thumbnail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do not want a screenshot to appear for your app, you can use

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

on your `onCreate` method to display a blank screen instead.

Comment: Thanks you very much. 

1. Can we set custom screenshot instead of blank screen for our app which will display in thumb?
2. Can we override functionality to take screenshot?
3. How android take screenshot? Is android send broadcast?